# Why is there a merge conflict during an interactive rebase to remove a simple commit?

Tags: git

I have a git repo where I want to remove a single commit from so I use `git rebase -i 710b5ec51ff` to do so. The commit contains 1 file called "*intro.cpp*". The rebase begins and eventually fails with:

```
error: could not apply 5a91d7f2f9b... Remove string
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 5a91d7f2f9b... Update language
Auto-merging locales/language.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in locales/language.c
```

Why am I getting this conflict? I remember that I needed to resolve this conflict once a while ago. Why do I need to do that again, although both commits (the one I want to remove, and the one where it stops) are completely unrelated and don't share a file?

Comment: Are we possibly talking about https://medium.com/@porteneuve/fix-conflicts-only-once-with-git-rerere-7d116b2cec67 ?

Comment: Try viewing `locales/language.c` using nano/vim and you can see the cause of the merge conflict.

Comment: @fxdeaway I can see the conflict, but the quesiton is, why this conflict happens in the first place (again)

Comment: Thank you for the link! @skumar I am just wondering why Git wants to make this resolve in the first place

Comment: What exactly was the conflict? Could you please add it to your post?

Comment: I just checked the conflict again, it's just some lines coming into the file, nothing special

Comment: What original commits are you copying with this rebase, and what positions did they occupy in the commit graph *before* you started this rebase? In particular, was there a merge commit in the set of commits you started with? If not, this is probably a normal cherry-pick merge conflict. If so, this could be the result of flattening out some merge. (If the interactive rebase showed only one `pick` command, we're looking at a normal everyday cherry-pick merge conflict.)

Comment: In short, we need more information from you before we can answer your specific question. If you want to know in general why a cherry-pick operation can see a merge conflict, I can answer *that* question, but it won't show you why *your particular* one is getting your particular conflict.